# A mysterious property of 17 US-states

Tags: pattern, geography

There are 17 US-states that share a certain (purely geographical) property that the remaining 33 US-states do not have. Here are 15 of the 17:

> Arizona, Arkansas, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Indiana, Iowa, Mississippi, 
>   Ohio, Oklahoma, Rhode Island, South Carolina, Utah, West Virginia, Wyoming

**Which are the two missing states on this list?**
**What is this mysterious purely geographical property?**

Comment: It is a mysterious property, but is it enigmatic?

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a labelled map of the US.

Comment: What does purely geographical mean? Rivers, mountains, lakes?

Comment: Putely geographic means centered around countries, continents, cities, mountains, rivers, people, culture, climate, and other phenomena of the Earth.

Comment: In this case purely geographic means one out of the following three: cities, mountains, rivers.

Comment: I can't decide whether changing 32 to 33 would be a trivial edit so I'll let someone else do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems likely that the geographic feature you're referring to is

> the state's capital city also being the state's largest city

but every source I can find shows 17 states with that quality, not 18.  Those 17 are the 15 you listed plus

> Colorado and Massachusetts.

For example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States) shows 17, using census data published in 2012, and there are also 17 on [this handy map](http://www.businessinsider.com/state-capitals-largest-cities-map-2014-10) using 2010 census data.  Is it possible you used an outdated source, or miscounted?  Or did you have a completely different geographic feature in mind, making this an unbelievable coincidence?

Comment: I made a mistake, I had Minnesota on my list.  I have corrected the problem.